# Remove Icon in QListView

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a class that creates a QListView item, and the following functions that add items to the the list and also add icons to specific items in the list. Having a hard time figuring out how to remove an icon from a single item (or even all items) in the list.

```
self.list_view = ui_object.ListView(width=350, height=150) # This is just a custom QListView Class
self.model = QStandardItemModel(self.list_view)
self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
self.list_view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

@pyqtSlot(object)
def add_chargecode(self, matching_names):

    for name in matching_names:
        item = QStandardItem(name)
        self.model.appendRow(item)

def set_as_default(self, chargecode):
    chargecode_list = self.model.findItems(chargecode, Qt.MatchExactly)

    for item in chargecode_list:
        item.setData(QIcon(self.ctx.delete_icon['red']), Qt.DecorationRole)

def remove_icon(self, chargecode):
    chargecode_list = self.model.findItems(chargecode, Qt.MatchExactly)

    for item in chargecode_list:
        item... # Help ? Remove Icons for These Items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass None as the value associated with the role `Qt::DecorationRole`:

```py
for item in chargecode_list:
    item.setData(None, Qt.DecorationRole)
```